# Infix search in MySQL (search with pattern in the middle) with an index

Tags: python, mysql, search, full-text-search, innodb

I have a MySQL 8 InnoDB compressed table, with an index:

```
set global innodb_file_per_table=1;
create table t (id int primary key auto_increment, 
                key varchar(200), value varchar(200))
                  row_format=compressed engine=innoDB;
create index key_index on t(key) using BTREE;
create index value_index on t(value) using BTREE;
```

For 20 million items, a (prefix) search like

```
select * from t where key like "hello%"
```

takes a few milliseconds (thanks to the index!) ... but an *(infix)* search like

```
select * from t where key like "%hello%"
```

takes 40 seconds.

**How to speed up such queries?** I have read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html but I don't want to use a too complex tool: what is the lightest solution, to be able to do searches like:

```
 ******abc***************************
  |     |                        |
  |     an exact sequence        |
  |                              |
  0, 1 or many characters        0, 1 or many characters
```

Note: I'm using `mysql-8.0.33-winx64` and Python (`import mysql.connector`).

Comment: PS: is it possible to add this feature after the table has aleady been populated? (`ALTER TABLE ...`)

Comment: Please add some sample data with typical values for `key` and `value`, and some examples of the strings used in your _"infix"_ searches. Additional context may help too.

Comment: @user1191247 `key` and `value` can be a few words from dictionnary (with or without spaces) or even random chars, etc.: `"blablablahelloabcdefgh"` is an example of `key`. I would be able to find `%hello%` without a full table scan :)

Answer (score 1):

If a fulltext index is too complex for your taste, then the only other methods to speed up the query are:

- Get a faster computer
- Delete millions of rows of data until the table is small and a table-scan is quick enough.

The query you show with a wildcard at the start of the pattern, is bound to do a table-scan, even though you have a b-tree index. That sort of pattern matching cannot use a b-tree index.

Think of the analogy to a telephone book. The book is sorted by last name and first name. If you look up someone by their last name, you can search quickly because it's sorted. But if you search for people whose last name has some pattern of characters *in the middle*, the fact that the book is sorted by last name doesn't help. You still have to look at every entry on every page. That's like a table-scan in a database.

The FULLTEXT index in MySQL might not help either. It helps if you are searching for a whole word, but not for arbitrary patterns or substrings, because it doesn't support a leading wildcard search.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html says:

> `*`
>
> The asterisk serves as the truncation (or wildcard) operator. Unlike
> the other operators, it is appended to the word to be affected. Words
> match if they begin with the word preceding the `*` operator.

You can't use this wildcard *before* the word, only *after* a word prefix. That's just the way this feature is implemented in current versions of MySQL.

MySQL supports generated columns and indexes on such columns, so you could create an index on the `LIKE` expression:

```
alter table t 
  add column contains_hello boolean as (email like '%hello%'),
  add key (contains_hello);
```

Then search that column for rows where it is true:

```
select * from t where contains_hello = true;
```

This will use the index, but only for the pattern `'%hello%'` that is fixed in the definition of the generated column. You can't make a generated column that takes a parameter for any argument.

Basically, there are no good options. Creating an index for any new pattern is at least as expensive as doing the table-scan (in fact more expensive).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BillKarwin. Then let's go for FTS! What is the smallest footprint solution to do this just to be able to do a `LIKE "%pattern%"`? Can we do this with `ALTER TABLE ...`?

Comment: Thanks for your edit! Unfortuantely, `%hello%` is just an example, and it will be different for each query, so this generated-column solution is not an option. Aren't there ways to speed up queries in the middle? For example with bi-grams (I don't remember exactly)? How do search engine do to allow search in the middle? Do you think it would be possible with another RDBMS like PostgreSQL?

Comment: Your question was about MySQL, not PostgreSQL. Each other RDBMS has its own fulltext implementation with different features. There are also specialized text-search indexing tools like ElasticSearch or Sphinx Search. I'm not going to evaluate all of these, you can do your own research.